# access scope from directive with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

How can I access the controller's scope properties with my custom `TypeScript` directive?
for example, in the following snippet I want to log `scope.message`:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

//module
module app {
    var mainModule = angular.module('mainModule', []);
}

//controller
module app.testCtrl {
    interface ITest {
        message: string;
    }

    class TestCtrl implements ITest {
        message: string = 'initial value'; // this is the value i want to access from my dierctive
    }
    angular.module('mainModule').controller('testCtrl', TestCtrl);
}

//directive
module app.directives {
    export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict = 'A';

        static instance(): ng.IDirective {
            return new MyDirective;
        }

        link(scope: ng.IScope) {
            //HOW DO I GET TO THE SCOPE PROPERTIES?
            //console.log(scope.???);
        }

    }
    angular.module('mainModule').directive('myDirective', MyDirective.instance);
}
```

P.S - I'm using the "controller as" syntax on the view if that makes a difference

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do that, seems like you are abusing it. You can do `console.log(scope.myControllerAsAlias.message);` though. But the 'angular way' is to pass properties to the directive instead of reading them out of the controller

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are abusing the concepts of angular's directives. You can access the controller's scope variables if you do something like this:

```
link(scope: ng.IScope) {
    console.log(scope["myControllerAsAlias"].message);
}
```

However, the 'angular way' would be to pass the variable to the directive, something like this:

```
interface IMyDirectiveScope extends ng.IScope {
    message: string
}

export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'A';
    scope = {
        message: "@"
    };

    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new MyDirective;
    }

    link(scope: IMyDirectiveScope) {
        console.log(scope.message);
    }

}
```

And in your html:

```
<div my-directive message="myCtrlAsAlias.message"></div>
```

Comment: `scope.vm.message` gives a "property doesn't exist error". `scope['vm'].message` works. question is how do I use it (the second suggestion) on an input? or maybe I should target the `ngModel` instead? couldn't implement it as well...

Comment: Please explain your goal exactly. This answer answered your question, but it seems like you've only asked a small part of what you really want to achieve